# Can I use `bazel cquery` to determine which `config_setting` rules are being activated?

Tags: bazel, boringssl

I have a dependent library that appears to be choosing the wrong `config_setting`.

In order to debug this further, I have tried using the `config` function from the `cquery` docs, but it returns *all* the potential config_settings.

Specifically, I tried running the following:
`bazel cquery "config(deps(@openssl//:crypto), target)" --noimplicit_deps
--bazelrc=build-scripts/windows/windows.bazelrc`

It returned:

```
@openssl//:crypto (aa65f203efeb0a68bcf0a0d51b3259145cb8e2c6bf209950206fe2bfb21381b5)
@local_config_cc//:cc-compiler-k8 (aa65f203efeb0a68bcf0a0d51b3259145cb8e2c6bf209950206fe2bfb21381b5)
@local_config_cc//:local (aa65f203efeb0a68bcf0a0d51b3259145cb8e2c6bf209950206fe2bfb21381b5)
@openssl//:windows_x86_64 (aa65f203efeb0a68bcf0a0d51b3259145cb8e2c6bf209950206fe2bfb21381b5)
@bazel_tools//tools/cpp:toolchain_type (aa65f203efeb0a68bcf0a0d51b3259145cb8e2c6bf209950206fe2bfb21381b5)
@openssl//:mac_x86_64 (aa65f203efeb0a68bcf0a0d51b3259145cb8e2c6bf209950206fe2bfb21381b5)
@openssl//:linux_ppc64le (aa65f203efeb0a68bcf0a0d51b3259145cb8e2c6bf209950206fe2bfb21381b5)
@openssl//:android (aa65f203efeb0a68bcf0a0d51b3259145cb8e2c6bf209950206fe2bfb21381b5)
```

What is the best way to determine how Bazel is selecting a `config_setting`? Is it cquery?

I expected my above command to not return any build rules related to the mac, linux, and android config settings. Just the windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the best solution for my needs was to do run cquery on my target of interest and then examine the configured build files (`output=build` in the cquery)
to see which values were getting chosen by the `select` statements.

It would still be nice to have the option of seeing some sort of "config setting resolution" process in the logs. But this gets the job done for now.